# Freezing app with Esky and zmq modules

Tags: python, cx-freeze, pyzmq, esky

I'm trying to freeze my app using Esky and cx_freeze.

My setup.py looks something like this:

```
from esky.bdist_esky import Executable
from distutils.core import setup
includes = ["zmq"]
exe = Executable("main.py")

setup(
    name = "Jarvis",
    version = "0.1",
    options = {"bdist_esky" : {"includes" : includes, "freezer_module": "cxfreeze"}},
    scripts = [exe],
)
```

However, it seems like pyzmq is not properly included in the freeze.

I keep getting:

```
PS C:\jarvis\dist> .\main.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__main__.py", line 838, in <module>
  File "__main__.py", line 331, in bootstrap
  File "__main__.py", line 358, in chainload
  File "__main__.py", line 834, in _chainload
  File "main.py", line 50, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 32, in start_agent
  File "jarvis\agent\agent.pyc", line 1, in <module>
  File "zmq\__init__.pyc", line 62, in <module>
  File "zmq\backend\__init__.pyc", line 22, in <module>
  File "zmq\backend\select.pyc", line 31, in select_backend
  File "zmq\backend\cffi\__init__.pyc", line 12, in <module>
  File "zmq\backend\cffi\constants.pyc", line 4, in <module>
  File "zmq\backend\cffi\_cffi.pyc", line 18, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cffi
```

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

**EDIT2:**: ok, there is an answer that solved it for me >>
https://bitbucket.org/anthony_tuininga/cx_freeze/issue/55/failed-with-pyzmq-1401-py33-win-amd64egg

**EDIT**: as suggested, have been forced to use cython backend there is another error stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27
, in <module>
    exec code in m.__dict__
  File "send.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\__init__.py", line 70, in <module>
    from zmq.backend import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\__init__.py", line 23, in <mod
ule>
    _ns = select_backend(backend)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\select.py", line 31, in select
_backend
    mod = __import__(name, fromlist=public_api)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\zmq\backend\cython\__init__.py", line 26,
in <module>
    from . import (constants, error, message, context,
  File "ExtensionLoader_zmq_backend_cython_error.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "ExtensionLoader_zmq_backend_cython_error.py", line 14, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

I guess there is a problem with loading native `libzmq.dll` (however, there is some `zmq.libzmq.pyd` in the resulting `dist` folder), have anybody solved this?

Comment: ZMQ tries to load its Cython backend first, and then falls back to the cffi backend if that fails. Put an `import zmq.backend.cython` in your code (before the current failing import) to see what problem it's having with the Cython backend.

Comment: this does not help, the stack trace remains the same

Comment: Succeeded forcing cython backend by: `os.environ['PYZMQ_BACKEND'] = 'cython'` prior to `import zmq`